# WPF: Implementing scalable Custom Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I'm working on a ColorPicker Control and decided it would be best to compose it of primitive Controls to be able to  rearrange the various sliders and the color wheel in a control template without having to redefine everything. (Also the Controls code would become pretty messy)

I have created a new Template for the `Slider` Control and I want it to be scalable. For now, the size of the thumb is fixed, as is the center "Track".

```
<Style x:Key="ColorSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Width="80" Height="480" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.0"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>

                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="ValueThumb">
                                    <Thumb.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Canvas Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                                            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="20" Fill="Transparent"/>
                                                            <Polygon Points="0,0 0,20 10,10" Fill="Black" />
                                                            <Polygon Points="100,0 100,20 90,10" Fill="Black" />
                                                        </Canvas>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Thumb.Style>
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: ColorPicker Control]

One way to make the control scalable would be to use a `Grid` however that would get messy as well since the thumb would have to  extend over 3 columns and it would then be difficult to get the proportions of the thumb right.

Are there any best practices for making a control scalable? A Viewbox for example would only magnify the result and probably lower the visual quality. Are there any other methods that one could use?

UPDATE 1: To address the comments: here is an example using a Grid:

```
<Style x:Key="ColorSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="5" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="5" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="10" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.0"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>

                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="ValueThumb">
                                    <Thumb.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Canvas Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                                            <Rectangle Height="20" Fill="Transparent"/>
                                                            <Polygon Points="0,0 0,20 10,10" Fill="Black" />
                                                            <Polygon Points="100,0 100,20 90,10" Fill="Black" />
                                                        </Canvas>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Thumb.Style>
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

this however still won't scale the thumb triangles and there is also a visual problem for which I have no idea how it could be solved in XAML only. That is, the thumb extends over the bar to the bottom.

[image: See the bug]

UPDATE 2: To make the question more specific and hopefully less "opinion based", the question can be reformulated to:

**What options does one have available to make a control composed of various parts and the example above in particular scalable.**

Comment: adorners can be your your choice here. secondly viewbox may not reduce the quality unless you have the raster content.

Comment: Use a grid with *-sized rows and columns where you want the control to grow. Why is that "messy" and "difficult to get the proportions of the thumb right"?

Comment: Your question is off topic for this website because it is primarily opinion based: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* If you do not edit it to make it less opinion based then the Stack Overflow community will vote to close it.

Comment: @pushpraj sorry I don't see how Adorners can be used here, for it's the thumb that extends over the bar itself. Allthough you are right, Viewboxes won't lower the quality if vector graphics are used.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I have added an example using Grids to illustrate the arising issues, or better what issues the Grid can't solve.

Comment: @Sheridan I have changed the question. Allthough it was formulated a bit like an opinion based question, it's not (in my opinion :P). The question is about solving a particular scaling issue and is asking for a solution (any solution first of all) which has considerable, measurable advantages over other solutions.

Comment: @Xaser, thank you for your edit. I have now removed my down vote accordingly. However, please note for the future, any question title with the words *Best Practice* in is always deemed to be *primarily opinion based*.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is going to be a viewbox.

http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html